# sapui5 VizFrame with responsive grid variable width/span

Tags: sapui5

My app has a page with multiple vizFrames (pie or bar charts) side by side. They are wrapped in a grid using an XML View.

```
<l:Grid id="grid" defaultSpan="XL3 L4 M6 S12">
    <l:content>
        <viz:VizFrame id="idPie1" width="100%"></viz:VizFrame>              
        <viz:VizFrame id="idChart1" width="100%"></viz:VizFrame>
...
```

I want one of the VizFrame's to have a different SPAN than the default provided for the Grid. I tried

```
<viz:VizFrame id="idPie1" width="100%">
  <layoutData> 
    <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
  </layoutData>
</viz:VizFrame>
```

but without success.

Here is the coding in a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/VoHVBeNWDEpPoDzo9Upy/)

Comment: Did you try it like this:
`<l:Grid id="grid" defaultSpan="XL3 L4 M6 S12">
    <l:content>
        <viz:VizFrame id="idPie1" width="100%">
            <layoutData> 
               <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
            </layoutData>
        </viz:VizFrame>
...`
as can be seen [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.GridTiles/code/Grid.view.xml) ?

Do you get any error messages in the console?
Maybe it helps if you could post your example in a tool like plunkr (plnkr.co) to make it easier for debugging.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this gives the following error: sap-ui-core.js:152 Uncaught Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame. I don't use the newest sapui5 version: 1.30.10. I'll try to copy it into a plunkr.

Comment: Thanks for your plnkr example.
We can reproduce the problem and we are looking into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try:

```
<viz:layoutData> <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" /> </viz:layoutData>
```

Comment: This does at least not throw a syntax error. However the span set in the layoutData is not respected.
`<l:Grid id="dashboardGrid" defaultSpan="XL4 L4 M6 S12">
   <l:content>
           <viz:VizFrame id="idChart" width="100%">
   <viz:layoutData> 
        <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
    </viz:layoutData>
 </viz:VizFrame> 
   <viz:VizFrame id="idChart1" width="100%">    
  </viz:VizFrame>
...`

Comment: In your plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/VoHVBeNWDEpPoDzo9Upy?p=preview
I can see a difference in layout, when I insert “<viz:layoutData> <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" /> </viz:layoutData>”
into the first vizframe, as indicated by your comment there.I also tried with different values and it seemed to get applied ok.
In the plunkr you have the coding on the left and the preview on the right.
I also see a difference in layout, if I resize the preview by moving the line in the middle of the plunkr.
Have you tried resizing the window ?
Which device are you using for the display ?

Comment: I have updated the punkr and it seems to indeed work there. I'm just testing on chrome on windows at present. Let me try it in eclipse, too. I will confirm in case it works.